# Transposing Only one column in the Datatable

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a DataTable like below:

[image]

I like to transpose the above table as below:

[image]

I am able to bring the Header values using the below code:

```
 DataTable outputTable = new DataTable();
        outputTable.Columns.Add(inputTable.Columns[0].ColumnName.ToString());
        int rCount = 0;
        foreach (DataRow inRow in inputTable.Rows)
        {

            string DescColName = inRow[1].ToString();
            string maxColName = "MaxValue";
            string valColName = "Status";
            outputTable.Columns.Add(DescColName);
            outputTable.Columns.Add(maxColName);
            outputTable.Columns.Add(valColName);
        }
```

I am trying the below code to fill the rows which is failing.

```
for (int rCount = 0; rCount <= inputTable.Columns.Count - 1; rCount++)
        {
            DataRow newRow = outputTable.NewRow();

            for (int cCount = 0; cCount <= inputTable.Rows.Count - 1; cCount++)
            {
                string colValue = inputTable.Rows[cCount][rCount].ToString();
                newRow[cCount] = colValue;
            }
            outputTable.Rows.Add(newRow);

        }
```

Comment: What is the error message you're getting? Please post it exactly as it appears.

Answer (score 0):

I think I understand why it's failing.

In your second block of code, if keep track of `rCount` and `cCount` on these lines:

```
string colValue = inputTable.Rows[cCount][rCount].ToString();
newRow[cCount] = colValue;
```

what your resulting data table would look like is

```
02/18/2014 | 02/18/2014 | 02/18/2014 | 02/19/2014 | 02/19/2014 | 02/19/2014 | ... //and on and on
Tire Alignment | Oil Change | Air Filter| Tire Alignment | Oil Change | Air Filter| ... //and on and on
```

etc. So if you have more rows in your inputTable than you have columns in your outputTable, at some point your `cCount` is going to go past the number of available columns in `newRow`. I suspect this is what is happening to cause the error. Unfortunately, in order to account for multiple rows having the same report date, I'm afraid you might have to rework your entire solution.

Comment: Yes I understand the problem, but cant we solve and achive this solution?

Comment: I'd love to help you, but I'm not going to do any coding for you unless you want to pay me :). Your question was about the reason it's failing. If you agree that my answer as to why it was failing is correct, please mark it as the solution. (I did, after all, have to analyze your code.) If you want to edit your post with your updated attempts I'd be glad to continue providing insight.

Comment: Just to point you in the direction that I would go, I would begin by switching your `rCount` and `cCount` variables and adding an if statement in your inner loop to check if the report date has changed from the report date in `newRow`. It would also be wise to sort your datatable by ReportDate before going into your loops.